# Passing formulas from R to Julia via XRJulia

Tags: r, julia

I'm trying to use Julia from R via XRJulia to fit some regression models. I'd like to pass the R data and formula objects to Julia. Here's where I'm at so far:

```
library(XRJulia)
findJulia(test=T) # Works fine
juliaEval("using MixedModels")

jlmerj<-juliaEval("
 function(f,d)
   m=fit(LinearMixedModel,f,d)
   return(m)
 end
 ")
jlmer=JuliaFunction(jlmerj)

jdata<-juliaSend(data[,c('IRI_EC','learnid')])
jfrm<-juliaEval("@formula(IRI_EC ~  1 + (1|learnid))")
```

At this point, jdata and jfrm appear to be Julia proxy objects:

```
> jdata
Julia proxy object
Server Class: Dict{String,Any}; size: 7
> jfrm
Julia proxy object
Server Class: StatsModels.Formula; size: NA
```

But this call fails (vaguely):

```
res<-jlmer(jfrm,jdata)
Error: Evaluating Julia expression: R_1_7(R_1_9, R_1_29)
```

(R_1_7, etc. are the names of the functions as returned by juliaName(jlmerj), juliaName(jfrm), juliaName(jdata)). The same model syntax works fine in JuliaCall (I'm trying to convert to XRJulia because JuliaCall only seems to print out the results of the fit without returning anything I can usefully convert back to an R object).

Other juliaEvals of functions and the like work, but I can't get anything with formula objects to work.

Has anyone done this? How?

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of JuliaCall. As far as I know, JuliaCall does return the julia object from the function and will try to convert the julia object to R object; and in the case that the automatic conversion fails, return a wrapper for the julia object, very similar to the julia proxy object in XRJulia. The only difference is that XRJulia shows julia proxy object in a very succinct form and JuliaCall gives quite verbose information so maybe that's why you think JuliaCall only print out results?

Comment: And you can use either julia functions to extract information from the returned object or use some utility functions provided by JuliaCall to extract information in some simple cases. BTW, I'm not very familiar with the MixedModels package. Could you provide some dataset and the commands you use in JuliaCall for me to check? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't really clear. Yes, JuliaCall does return a Julia object or wrapper and I have been able to extract some things from it - I think the issue is MixedModels doesn't really document its return values so well, so it's hard to pry what I'm looking for out of them (it has various extractors but some are not yet up to the full capabilities of the models it can fit). So the part of the question about JuliaCall (which is really amazing) is likely moot.

That said, I really am curious about how to get a formula passed to a function in XRJulia as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please give an example data set to run your code?

After checking this again, I suspect the problem is not with the formula but with the conversion of R `data.frame` in `XRJulia`, since in your message you can see that `jdata` is a proxy of a `Dict` (dictionary) instead of a `DataFrame` or similar things in `julia`. And I also (briefly) check in `MixedModels` and it seems that the package can't deal with a `Dict` as a dataset.

The usage of `JuliaCall` is somewhat similar to `XRJulia` but it will convert R `data.frame` to `julia` `DataFrame`. And the use of `XRJulia` in your examples seems okay with me. So the fact that this works with `JuliaCall` but not `XRJulia` also implies that the problem is with the conversion of `data.frame` in `XRJulia`.

It may be that `XRJulia` currently lacks the ability to convert `data.frame`s in R.
If this is the case, I can think two (theoretically) possible ways to deal with the problem, the first is to read the dataset into `julia` directly as a `DataFrame`, the other is to convert the `Dict` to `DataFrame` in your `jlmerj` function. And if an example dataset is given, I can try the solutions on the dataset.

BTW, authors of `MixedModels` has spoken with me about possibilities to build an R package based on `MixedModels` using `JuliaCall`, if that happens, I think it can be a lot of easier to try `MixedModels` from R.

Update 1: an example on converting dataframe in `XRJulia` for the specific minidataset

```
library(XRJulia)
findJulia(test = T) # Works fine
juliaEval("using MixedModels")

juliaEval("using DataFrames")

jlmerj <- juliaEval("
                  function(f,d)
                  m=fit(LinearMixedModel,f,d)
                  return(m)
                  end
                  ")
jlmer <- JuliaFunction(jlmerj)

mindata <- data.frame(IRI_EC = c(15, 14, 27, 0, 22, 16, 23, 17, 20, 26), learnid = factor(1:10))

jfrm <- juliaEval("@formula(IRI_EC ~  1 + (1|learnid))")

jIRI_EC <- juliaSend(mindata$IRI_EC) ## send columns one by one
## first convert factors to integers and convert back in julia
jlearnid <- juliaCall("CategoricalArrays.CategoricalArray", juliaSend(as.integer(mindata$learnid))

## combine columns to create dataframe in julia
jdata <- juliaEval(paste0('DataFrame(Dict([(:IRI_EC,', juliaName(jIRI_EC),
                          '), (:learnid, ', juliaName(jlearnid), ')]))'))

res <- jlmer(jfrm,jdata)

res
```

Comment: Here is a minimal data set that produces the same result:

Comment: Here is a minimal data set that produces the same result:

     mindata<-data.frame(IRI_EC = c(15, 14, 27, 0, 22, 16, 23, 17, 20, 26), learnid = factor(1:10))

    jdata<-juliaSend(mindata[,c('IRI_EC','learnid')])

    > jdata
    Julia proxy object
    Server Class: Dict{String,Any}; size: 7

Comment: I've tried to convert the R dataframe to julia dataframe and succeeded, but the process is not easy and is specialized for this simplified data set which is a little hard to generalize. You can see my updated post for the process. I think it may be better to read the data directly into julia.

Comment: Wow, that's ... interesting. That's a good argument for JuliaCall instead. :) Appreciate the help.